# Skew fragment like Apps app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been inspired by the Apps app on my Galaxy S4 to implement a skew on a fragment if a user attempts to swipe farther than the bounds of my view pager. Does anyone have any tips on how to achieve this?

### The left most fragment of the Apps app's view pager:

[image: The left most fragment of the Apps app's view pager]

### When I try to swipe left:

[image: When I try to swipe left]

Answer (score 1):

This is not skew, this is a rotation and you can achieve it by:

```
    mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(View page, float position){
                page.setRotationY(position * -50);
        }
    });
```

you can play with `position` and `page` to create really cool animation.

Comment: I didn't know about PageTransformers. I thought this would be exactly what I wanted but it isn't. What I screenshot is the behavior of the pager when I'm on page 0 (the leftmost page) and attempt to scroll more to the left, out of the pager's bounds. How would I go about doing that?